# Setting default dependencies in start.spring.io

Tags: spring-boot

I have cloned a local copy of the start.spring.io UI project. I want to have a pre-selected dependency whenever the page is loaded. I was thinking it could be easier to modify this UI project instead of the Initializr project.

I could not find the place to set this pre-selected dependency part. Anyone have done before?

So for example in the screenshot below, I would like Lombok to be pre-selected:

[image]

Comment: Just as you would use the 'SHARE'-button? Like [spring-boot-with-lombok](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.5.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=lombok)

Comment: Hm then i would like the user when accessing the page perhaps on this link: http://company.com/springio/ to automatically be directed to the 'SHARED' link. I am using Kong as API gateway. I tried adding 'request-transformer' to replace the URI but cant get it to work.